# JasperReports: printing data in tabular form

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am getting the data in plain form.

How can I print the data in tabular form and export the report to pdf or html file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CROSSTAB report OR you can put separate lines for each columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways:

- You can fill the FIELDS in jrxml file using custom datasource or JDBC datasource, through which we can specify the field names and field mapping and iterations through fields.

Refer this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/63568/open-source/Creating-Data-Table-Jasper-Report

- Else you can use SUBREPORTS to achieve this task. Using subreports you can easily fill the table like structure in similar way as i said earlier, difference between previous method and this is previous we can have only one table in page, but by using subreports we can have/fill multiple tables in same page.

Refer this link 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/92938/java/Creating-custom-datasource-Jasper-Reports